# Batch Normalization

Tags: machine-learning, pattern-recognition

I've read a lot about batch normalization and how it is implemented. But I couldn't understand when to use batch normalization or not. What should we notice about the CNN to know that a batch normalization would give us an improvement on the accuracy?